# Swift and regex, cpu goes haywire for some strings

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I want to match a localization line with regex. Everything works fine except when trying to match this string. You can put the code in playground to see that it doesn't stop, or in a blank project to see the cpu going 100% and stuck at the 'let match' line. Now the interesting thing is if you delete the last word it works. I don't know if works with chinese or other weird chars, this is greek.

```
let lineContent = "\"key\" = \" Χρήση παλιάς συνόμευση\";"
if let r = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\"(.*)+\"(^|[ ]*)=(^|[ ]*)\"(.*)+\";", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions()) {
   let match = r.matchesInString(lineContent, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, lineContent.characters.count))
   match.count
}
```

**Later edit:** it actually doesn't matter the characters type but the number of words. This string put in the right side is also not working: 'jhg jhgjklkhjkh hhhhh hhh'

Comment: I think part of the problem is the first `(.*)+` - as it will capture everything ahead.  Try making it lazy: `(.*?)`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regex for that? Seems like a simple parser would do and be much more efficient.

Comment: You have nested quantifiers in `(.*)+` that will lead to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Perhaps something like `"\"([^\"]*)\"[ ]*=[ ]*\"([^\"]*)\";"`

Comment: Sideroxylon, Mariano thanks,both works, perhaps you can put it as an answer to accept the most lightning one. Kametrixom yes it worths doing a performance test to see which is better, i had a parser before and i'm trying to switch to something simpler, it was not even complete, i was checking for begin and end only and i had a case where the beginning was also the end: ";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested quantifiers in `(.*)+` that will lead to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) (I recommend reading that article). The problem is when a subexpression fails, the regex engine backtracks to test another alternative. Having nested quantifiers means there will be an exponencial number of tries for each character in the subject string: it will test for all repetitions of `(.*)+` and, for each, also all repetitions of `.*`.

To avoid it, use a pattern defined as specific as you can:

```
"\"([^\"]+)\"[ ]*=[ ]*\"([^\"]*)\";"
```

- `\"([^\"]+)\"` Matches

  - An opening `"`
  - `[^\"]+` Any number of characters except quotes. Change the `+` to `*` to allow empty strings.
  - A closing `"`

**Code**

```
let lineContent = "\"key\" = \" Χρήση παλιάς συνόμευση\";"
if let r = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\"([^\"]+)\"[ ]*=[ ]*\"([^\"]*)\";", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions()) {
    let match = r.matchesInString(
        lineContent,
        options: NSMatchingOptions(), 
        range: NSMakeRange(0, lineContent.characters.count)
    )

    for index in 1..<match[0].numberOfRanges {
        print((lineContent as NSString).substringWithRange(match[0].rangeAtIndex(index)))
    }
}
```

<kbd>[SwiftStub demo](http://swiftstub.com/976274880)</kbd>

Comment: I ended up using both solutions, this for the right side string, because accepts empty strings, and the other one for the left side string because i really need a string there and it doesn't accept empty strings

Comment: I changed the `*` to `+` to require the left side string

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comments, the `.*+` is causing a catastrophic backtracking, causing the high CPU usage (and in general, failure to match).

Instead of using a pattern like

```
\"(.*)+\"
```

since, you're matching everything between the double-quotes, use a negated character set:

```
\"([^\"]+)\"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment above - replace the nested `(.*)+` with a lazy version - `(.*?)`.